# Product Type with Properties

Tags: c#, entity-relationship, entity-framework-6

Hope someone can help me. I am trying to use product base catalog with predefined type. So for example there is a simple type and a advanced type of products those types have configurable properties. So i have a my models like below but i can't get the value stored in a diffrent table with a relation on the property en product.

I have added a desired json output below of a singel ProductDto object.. Wehere PropertyTypeValue must be the value of the property tided on the product.

I hoop i explained it correct.

```
[Table("Product")]
public class ProductDto
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }                        
    public virtual ProductTypeDto ProductType { get; set; }       

}

[Table("ProductType")]
public class ProductTypeDto
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PropertyTypeGroupDto> PropertyTypeGroups { get; set; }

}

[Table("PropertyTypeGroup")]
public class PropertyTypeGroupDto
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductTypeDto ProductType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PropertyTypeDto> PropertyTypes { get; set; }
}

[Table("PropertyType")]
public class PropertyTypeDto
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual PropertyTypeGroupDto PropertyTypeGroup { get; set; }
}

[Table("PropertyValue")]
public class PropertyValueDto
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductDto Product { get; set; }
    public virtual PropertyTypeDto PropertyType { get; set; }
}
```

```
        {
    productType: {
    propertyTypeGroups: [
    {
    propertyTypes: [
    {
    propertyTypeValue: null,
    id: "88c1e9ed-7b03-e411-8ca5-74d4351a6e12",
    name: "Sample Property 1"
    },
    {
    propertyTypeValue: null,
    id: "89c1e9ed-7b03-e411-8ca5-74d4351a6e12",
    name: "Sample Property 2"
    }
    ],
    id: "87c1e9ed-7b03-e411-8ca5-74d4351a6e12",
    name: "Sample Group"
    }
    ],
    id: "85c1e9ed-7b03-e411-8ca5-74d4351a6e12",
    name: "Simple Product",
    alias: "simpleproduct"
    },
    id: "86c1e9ed-7b03-e411-8ca5-74d4351a6e12",
    name: "Sample Product 1"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly include navigation properties in your linq queries like so:

```
var productValue = this.Context.PropertyValues.Include(p => p.Product).FirstOrDefault(pv => pv.Id == someId);
```